# Difference between socket creation in Java using string as IP & reading IP from file?

Tags: java, string, file, sockets

I am facing a problem . I am reading an IP from a file and trying to create & connect to a socket.

But reading from file always shows the same IP still it fails in connecting with following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

Logs:

```
Inside While Loop - Thread started in Client 

192.168.1.12
Calling Last Modified file in Client 

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Code:

```
r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/ip.txt")); 
client = new Socket(r.readLine(),8880);
```

Strangely , If i do this :

```
client = new Socket("192.168.1.12",8880);
```

It works. But both IP's are same . r.readline() returns the same IP.

Need inputs here .

Thanks
NJ

Comment: If you do a simple `System.out.println` of r.readLine() to see its output, are you sure you are getting the expected output

Comment: Yes i had my logs on . It returns 192168.1.12. See the logs : 
Inside While Loop - Thread started in Client 

192.168.1.12
Calling Last Modified file in Client 

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: @gueverra We(and you)  can't see from those logs if the string contains some odd whitspace characters. Nor can you see if your `r.readLine()` call returned a seemingly empty line.  Your code should do this: `String ip = r.readLine(); System.out.printf("Read IP: '%s'\n"); client = new Socket(ip,8880);`   (With the single quotes in the printf() statement  you will see if there is whitespace in there)

Comment: The message "connection refused" usually means there's nothing listening on the port you are using. Make sure the server software is running.

Comment: @Joni More than likely the op has read an empty line from his text file or has reached the end of the file, and is effectively calling `new Socket("", 8880);` or `new Socket((String)null,  8880)` , both cases will try to connect to localhost instead of an IP address stated in the text file. Thus my suggestion of actually printing out the line read from the file instead of blindly passing it to the socket constructor as in `new Socket(in.readLine(), 8880)`

Comment: @nos i did print , it ruturns null  using this code                  String ip = r.readLine();
                 System.out.printf("Read IP: '%s'\n",ip); 
                 client = new Socket(ip,8880);

Comment: So the file is empty, or you had already called `readLine()`, in code you haven't posted.

Comment: @gueverra Well, perhaps you reached the end of your file. You should check for in.readLine() returning null, and not create a new socket if it does. You should also post the relevant code you have, not just small lines from it. When the people that can help you can see the same code that you can see, you will get much better and faster help.

Answer (score -2):

Need to read the line evrytime from the file . It was mgoing to read nextline which was null . So  aligned all the code together .

```
            r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/ip.txt"));
            String ip = r.readLine();
            System.out.printf("Read IP: '%s'\n",ip); 
            client = new Socket(ip,8880);
```

It worked!!

Comment: I never said iw as reading the file in every Loop and that was the issue .